# Microtiter Dish Biofilm Formation Assay- Pseudomonas and Crystal Violet

Tags: cell-biology

If Pseudomonas is a gram negative bacteria, it does not retain crystal violet but why is it that so many people are using crystal violet staining in theri Microtiter Dish Biofilm Formation Assay?

Comment: Could you provide more context? A citation to a paper that uses this assay?

Comment: heres an assay citation: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21307833

Comment: I think the answer is along the lines of: gram negative bacteria still use glycans externally when they form biofilms and stain with Methyl violet as a result.

Comment: So effectively, we not not actually enumerating the number of cell but instead the extend of the biofilm matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gram stain for differentiation between G- and + requires the addition of alcohol, the critical step in Gram staining. Actually the first step, simple staining, goes the same for all types of bacteria. All bacteria gain the stain, but addition of alcohol makes the lipid in bacteria like Pseudomonas to lose it.